# Magento 2 custom field not exists in request

Tags: magento2, product, custom-field

I have added a custom row builder using phtml (template) to product creation form.

However, when I submit the form, it does not send my custom input values to the server.

my phtml file is like the below:

```
<div id="properties-container">
    <table class="properties">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Value')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')) ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="properties-row-container"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p id="max-properties-message" style="display: none;" class="message notice limit" role="alert">
                        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Number of properties exceeded')) ?></span>
                    </p>

                    <button id="add-property" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Property')) ?></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <?php echo $block->getHtml(); ?>
</div>

<script id="properties-row-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <td>
        <input id="property-name<%- data._index_ %>" name="property[name][<%- data._index_ %>]" placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?>" class="admin__control-text w-100" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="property-value<%- data._index_ %>" name="property[value][<%- data._index_ %>]"  placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Value')) ?>" class="admin__control-text w-100" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="btn-remove<%- data._index_ %>" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</script>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "table.properties": {
            "fastentry/rowbuilder": {
                "rowTemplate": "#properties-row-template",
                "rowContainer": "#properties-row-container",
                "rowParentElem": "<tr></tr>",
                "remEventSelector": "button",
                "btnRemoveSelector": "[id^=btn-remove]",
                "maxRows": "30",
                "maxRowsMsg": "#max-properties-message",
                "addRowBtn": "#add-property",
                "additionalRowClass": "additional",
                "hideFirstRowAddSeparator": false,
                "formDataPost": <?php echo $block->getPropertiesJson() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are doing something in a really bad way, and it is hard to understand what you want to accomplish here. Also please consider to describe your custom row builder, because it  confuses me a lot.

Comment: i want to save some htmlContent fields in product product_form.xml how it could be?

Comment: add custom product field using htmlContent and save it. how can i do it?